# No operating system found specifically on reboot

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems, bootloader, bug

I've got a HP elitebook 8460p with linux installed on it. When I choose to reboot the system, at the time it starts it throws the 'no OS found' error. However if I shut it down and start it manually by button everything works as it should. This is not an error that takes place on a specific linux distribution but rather on all of them. I have tried it with Ubuntu, Arch, Debian and Mint. All of them show the same behaviour. I also tested with UEFI and legacy boot wich also behave the same way. The BIOS of the laptop states that UEFI is only meant to be used for testing/development purposes but I doubt this could be the problem as it persits with legacy boot too. Did anyone had the same problem and managed to solve it or does anyone with good knowledge of linux internals know what causes the 'no OS error' specifically on reboot and could maybe offer a solution?